# automate command prompt to copy file

Tags: command, command-prompt

I have the following file copy command.
How can I schedule this to run once a week automatically?

copy D:\SFTP*.* \location of file*.*
del D:\sftp*.* /q
exit

Thanks

Comment: See `at /?` at a command-prompt?

Comment: can elaborate on the above.

Comment: The `AT` command allows you to schedule a command/batch file to be run periodically.  I've barely used it (hence why I've not offered it as an answer), but `AT /?` seems to give enough help to get someone started.

Answer (score 0):

Task manager, set weekly and when

```
del d:\data\*.* /q
xcopy "C:\data\*.*" d:\data\*.* /y
del c:\data\*.* /q
```

Comment: Need this to run on a Thursday, every week

Comment: Windows has a Task scheduler, create a task to run this code saved as a .bat file